# onClick event doesn't fire if you move mouse

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple button like this:

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitActivity();">Add</a>
```

I also tried with:

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:submitActivity();">Add</a>
```

In both cases, it doesn't register the click if the mouse has moved a certain amount of pixels between mousedown and mouseup. This can lead users to believe they have submitted the info when they didn't

This is happening in Chrome. Haven't tested other browsers.

I want the event to fire regardless of where in the button you click and release.

Edit: The same thing is happening in Firefox, but visually it looks like I'm dragging the link. This way it at least makes sense to the user that it doesn't submit, but in Chrome there are no such visual indicator of what is happening.

Comment: you are actually dragging instead of clicking. That is usual browser behavior.

Comment: That is by design.  A better solution would be a notification to the user when successfully submitted.

Comment: Topener: I understand what is happening, but Chrome isn't giving any visual clue to the fact that you are dragging it.

mellamokb: But a user that hasn't submitted anything doesn't know to expect this notification.

Comment: Actually, I'm having exactly the same problem.  Chrome is sending my app an onclick event even when the mouse has moved drastically. And I don't want it to!

Comment: This button behaviour is extremely annoying when you use a graphics tablet to browse instead of the mouse. Graphics tablets aren't so stable (you are basically holding a pen), and they always move somewhat, so it's impossible to click buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to do a preventDefault() on onmousedown.

```
$(".button").mousedown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is pure jQuery, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I solved it using jquery since I was using that. The idea is to prevent default action on mousedown event in order to stop dragging of objects.

Comment: I know, nice one. But I cannot see the jQuery tag

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan $ denotes jquery

Comment: @gwnp "the jquery tag in the question tags"

Answer (score 4):

A click is defined as "holding down the mouse button, and then letting go of the mouse button." It is a combination of a mouse down and mouse up event executed on the same element. If the user moves away from the element, they are no longer executing a click, simply a mousedown (and also a mouseout, and then a mouseup on a different element).

This is standard, intuitive behavior. Users don't expect their click to "matter" unless they let go of the mouse without moving.

If for your application it is really important than ANY click result in this submit happening for you, then don't go with an onclick, go with onmousedown.

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="submitActivity();">Add</a>
```

EDIT: Misunderstood your problem. Perhaps this syntax that I am used to will work for you will work for you:

```
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add" name="add_button" onClick="submitActivity()">
```

Comment: This happens even though the cursor never leaves the object, just as long as it has moved a few pixels to the side before releasing. Having onmousedown is not really a good solution because that's not how buttons normally work + the :active styling doesn't come into play.

Comment: So how do we prevent a mouse down, significant mouse movement, then mouse up on the same element from causing an onclick?  when, for example the element is document.body, so no matter how far you move it's still a click (and you don't want it to be)?

Answer (score 1):

## *[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUpeR/1/)*

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseDown="submitActivity();">Add</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem but in another context. I created **custom buttons** using **divs** with onclick="..." and placing **child divs** into them for the button text and icon. When moving the cursor even one pixel over a child div between mousedown and mouseup, the parent div generated a mouseout event which prevented the click event to be fired. I could not find a way to disable the mouseout event, but found a simple CSS-solution to this problem. Just disable pointer-events for all children:

```
.buttondiv * {
    pointer-events: none; /* prevent click problems in buttons containing child divs */
}
```